# Preventing jQuery click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, onclick, event-listener

I have some links which I wish to prevent the user from unintentionally following if they have pending changes, and the following works.

```
$('#goToPage').next('ul.dropdown-menu').find('a').click(function(e){
    if (tinymce.activeEditor.isDirty() && !confirm("Are you sure")) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Similarly, I have dialog which I wish to do the same, and while the confirm prompt occurs before opening the dialog, however, `e.preventDefault();` does not prevent the dialog from opening.

How can an `click()` callback be disabled?  Note that the `#dialog-add` dialog is used on other pages and I don't wish to modify it.

```
$('#add').click(function(e){
    if (tinymce.activeEditor.isDirty() && !confirm("Are you sure")) {
        console.log('quit')
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
});

$("#add").click(function() {$("#dialog-add").dialog("open");});
$("#dialog-add").dialog();
```

Comment: The two click event listeners don't know about each other. Preventing default on one has no affect on the other. Combine the conditional logic into one. Could use part of url or perhaps a body class  to distinguish page types

Comment: @charlietfl  Ah, so that is is.  Thanks